# Rspec and watir-webdriver; running/skipping tests based on assertion?

Tags: rspec, filtering, watir-webdriver

I am looking for a way to include or exclude specific `it` blocks based on asserting the presence of a particular element. 
Background: I have a smoke test that looks at functionality of sections of elements.  My hope is to add more tests for additional functionality, but *only* if a specific section is present on the page. 
Pseudo code of my thoughts:

```
describe 'Smoking sections' do
    it 'runs test 1' do
        # does stuff
    end
    it 'runs test 2' do
        # does more stuff
    end
    # if foo_section.present? == true do
        # run additional tests using `it` blocks
    # else
        # p "Section not present"
    # end
    it 'continues doing more tests like normal' do
        # does additional tests
    end
end
```

Is this kind of filtering possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec provides a number of [approaches for skipping tests](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/skip-examples). In this case, you want to use the `skip` method within the example. This is most easily achieved by using a before hook to check for the section's presence.

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.describe 'Smoking sections' do
  it 'runs test 1' do
    # does stuff
  end

  it 'runs test 2' do
    # does more stuff
  end

  describe 'additional foo section tests' do
    before(:all) do
      skip('Section not present') unless foo_section.present?
    end

    it 'runs additional foo test' do
      # runs foo test
    end    
  end

  it 'continues doing more tests like normal' do
    # does additional tests
  end
end
```

Though you may want to consider designing your smoke test such that all tests should run. It might defeat the purpose if you have skippable tests.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking to do.  I agree that tests shouldn't be skipped--my current goal is to keep adding to my current smoke test until time is more on my side to refactor and break it out into smaller specs (i.e., more succinct) tests.

Comment: I do have one question though: when I set my spec up, it went through all of my existing `it` blocks _first_ and _then_ it went through the skippable one.  Is that as expected? I was under the impression it would run top-down, _including_ the skippable piece

Comment: That is expected. The [execution order is defined](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order) as examples top to bottom and then nested groups from top to bottom. Given the skippable tests were in a nested group, they ran last. You could change the nesting if you needed to get the tests into a specific order.